# Magento and UTF-8

Tags: magento, utf-8, payment-gateway

Has anybody had any experience with Magento and UTF-8?  It appears as though all of their systems require it.  For instance, during imports, we had particularly SKUs fail for really no reason that we could see.  When we opened the imports in Open Office and made sure we were saving in UTF-8, they worked fine.

I ask because we are setting up Magento's Payment Bridge.  When you set it up, it provides a merchant key and data transfer key you need to get it to all work.  As we set it up, the keys appear to be generated fine, but they are being stored and returned with weird characters in them.  We switched the my.cnf file to use UTF-8 by default in the database, and I've turned PuTTY (which I use for SSH) to be in UTF-8 as well, but we're still getting weird characters.  Any ideas as to how we can fix this and get the character set issue straightened out?  Has anyone had experience implementing Payment Bridge?

We are using Magento Professional, so we have limited support from them, but I wanted to reach out to the community and see if anyone has had a similar experience.

Comment: Could you please email me peter (at) magento.com with issue description and dump of PB DB? Where are you hosting? Please check if your DB supports UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

Those weird characters might be caused by too short fields in the merchant table. There are two files in the /sql directory upgrade_001.sql and upgrade_002.sql that need to be imported into database and the merchant information needs to be deleted and added again. This should help.